# Which state does a Fragment go into when the App is switched another Fragment?

Tags: android

this sounds like a basic question, but i couldnt find a proper answer.
I have 3 Fragments in 1 Activity. The Navigation is a Bottom Navigation Bar.

Fragment 1 has a CountdownTimer. When i switch to another Fragment, the CountdownTimer keeps running (as i want it), but the Texts are all reset to their original state.

So my question is, in which state does the Fragment fall, when i switch to another Fragment? Is there a difference between leaving it just for a moment and for longer/farther?

Also, is onCreateView called when i switch back to it, or only onResume?
I feel like onCreateView is called, because what else should reset all the texts? On the other hand, some methods i have in onCreateView are clearly NOT working when i switch back. Its a really weird behavior. I even have a method onCreateView that only gets half executed.

Comment: To understand it better I suggest you call all the lifecycle methods of activity and fragments in your activity and fragment classes respectively, put logs in each method and observe it at runtime while switching to fragments. I am telling you from experience that you will have far better understanding this way..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am still a beginner and avoided that "logging part" so far, do you have a tutorial or something that explains, how exactly i do that?

Comment: ok.. [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2432029) should get you going..

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks good.